# Prove that there does not exist group $G$ such that ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong \Bbb Z.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I know how to prove that for $\mathbb{Z}/n$ where $n$ is odd, but what should we do in case of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The proof is actually very similar to the case of $\mathbb{Z}/n$, how do you prove that fact?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/256173/337971

Comment: @CaptainLama The same way it's done here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2555701/731194

Comment: Well then it's the same thing, $G$ has an automophism of order 2, so its automorphism group is not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @dieSchizophren the proof in the link you give is incomplete (there is a lot of work wrapped up in the comment below the post!). The arguments that imply that abelian groups have automorphisms of order two the Axiom of Choice. Without Choice, it is consistent that there exists a group $G$ with infinite cyclic automorphism group.

Comment: @CaptainLama As far as I see, this proof is using Lagrange theorem, but if group is infinite we can't use it, right?

Comment: The point is that there is an automorphism of order $2$. If you want to conclude from that that the automorphism group cannot have odd order, you use Lagrange theorem. If you want to conclude that it cannot be $\mathbb{Z}$, it's even easier: elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ have infinite order.