# Prove that there does not exist a group $G$ with a group of automorphisms isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ with odd $n \gt 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove that there does not exist a group $G$ with a group of automorphisms isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with odd $n \gt 2$.

I assumed the opposite, let there exist a group $G$ such that $\mathrm{Aut} (G) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathrm{Aut} (G)  \cong  \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb {Z}$.
Since the subgroup of the cyclic group is also cyclic, $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is cyclic.
$\operatorname{Inn} (G) \cong G / Z (G) $.

So $G$ is Abelian.

If $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ has an element whose order is not equal to $2$, then we take the automorphism $p (x) = x^{-1}$. This is an automorphism of order $2$. There remains a case where the order of each automorphism is $2$. Help with this case.

Comment: For $\Bbb Z$ see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460694/prove-that-there-does-not-exist-group-g-such-that-rm-autg-cong-bbb-z?noredirect=1&lq=1).