# Prove there isn't a group $G$ that satisfy ${\rm Aut}(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

**Question:** Prove there isn't a group $G$ that satisfy ${\rm Aut}(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

I saw this similar question [Prove that there is no such group $G$ which would satisfy ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong\Bbb Z_n,$ where $n$ is an odd integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573170/there-does-not-exist-group-g-such-that-autg-cong-mathbbz-n-for-odd-n).

But I can't really understand why $n=1$ is trivial according to that commentary. Can someone give me a hint/help?

Comment: In the question you cite, they're trying to show that there is no $G$ such that $Aut(G) \cong \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$, which is very different than what you're trying to show. This theorem is actually *not* true for $n = 1$, since the zero group's group of automorphisms is $0$. Note that $\mathbb{Z} / 1 \mathbb{Z} \cong 0$.

Comment: This question is fully answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253936/is-every-group-the-automorphism-group-of-a-group)

Comment: @geep I've closed this as a duplicate, but do you understand MarkSavings explanation of the $n=1$ case? (The duplicate doesn't answer the $n=1$ question, but you are going down the wrong path with $n=1$ - really you want $n=\infty$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$, for whatever "$\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$" means.)

Answer (score 7):

$\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ being cyclic implies that $G$ is abelian. Now the automorphism $f : G \to G$ defined by $f(x) = x^{-1}$ has order $\leq 2$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no elements of order $2$, $f = \operatorname{id}_G$. Thus, every element of $G$ has order $1$ or $2$. This implies that $G$ is isomorphic to the additive group of an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space $V$, and it follows that $\mathbb{Z} \cong \operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong \operatorname{GL}(V)$. Since $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is abelian, $\dim(V) \leq 1$. Then $\operatorname{GL}(V) \cong \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$ for some $n \leq 1$, and thus $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is finite. This contradicts the prior deduction that $\operatorname{GL}(V) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.