# A question on the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a finite nonabelian group $G$, let $p$ be the smallest divisor of $|G|$. Then I want to show that

1. $p^2 |Z(G)| \le |G|$
2. If $N \le G$ is normal and $|N|=p$ then $N \le Z(G)$.

For the first one I think that since $G$ is non-abelian, $|G/Z(G)|>1$ and since $|G/Z(G)| $ divides $|G|$ then $|G/Z(G)|$ is at least $p$. However, in this case $G$ would be abelian. Then we must have $|G/Z(G)| \ge p^2$ thus $|G|\ge p^2 |Z(G)|$.

How can I show the second one?

Comment: What do you mean by ``in this case $G$ would be abelian''? In what case? Why not $p < |Z(G)| < p^2$? Part 2 follows from that fact that ${\rm Aut}(N)$ has order $p-1$, which is divisible only by primes less than $p$.

Comment: $Z(G)$ is of order $pk$ for some integer $k$ so that $pk$ divides $|G|$ but the smallest possible $k$ except $1$ is $p$ that is why I wrote in this way

Comment: Why $Aut(N)$ has order $p-1$?

Comment: Why is $Z(G)$ of order $pk$ for some integer $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G/Z(G)$ is not cyclic, and so $|G/Z(G)|$ is not a prime. Thus, $|G/Z(G)|\ge p^2$.

For the second question, it suffices to show that $C_G(N)=G$. Note that $N_G(N)/C_G(N)\lesssim\operatorname{Aut}(N)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785323/automorphism-group-of-a-cyclic-p-group)). As $p$ is the smallest prime divisor, it implies that $N_G(N)/C_G(N)=1$.

Comment: You should add that since $N$ is normal, $N_G(N)=G$.