# Given a group is finite and non-abelian, why is the left coset with the centre of the group non-cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Assume $T$ is finite and non-abelian then why is $T/Z(T)$ non-cyclic? Where $Z(T)$ is the centre of the group $T$.

I've shown $Z(T)$ is a normal subgroup of T, but not sure what to do next or if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma :$T/Z(T)$  is cyclic implies $T$ is abelian.

Proof:[Proving that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78690/proving-that-if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian?lq=1).
Can you conclude now?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to think of $T/Z(T)$ do we think of it as a subgroup?

Comment: What do you mean by as a "subgroup"?Don't you about know quotient groups?Don't you know that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $G/H$ is a group?

Comment: $T/Z(T)$ is the set of left (=right, since $Z(T)$ is normal in $T$) cosets of $Z(T)$ in $T$: $\{Z(T), t_1Z(T), t_2Z(T),\dots,t_nZ(T)\}$

Comment: You may read here about quotient groups:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group