# Finding a property for $G/Z(G)$ where $G$ is a nonabelian group

Tags: abelian-groups

If $G$ is non-abelian group and $Z(G)$ is it's center, what is the least property for $G$ such that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is abelian?

Comment: $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $H$ contains the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Specializing @DanielFischer , you need for all $a,b\in G$, $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in Z(G)$.

Comment: There are some interesting special cases that come up some times, such as if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It definitely comes up here more frequently than "some times", e.g., see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78690/proving-that-if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian?lq=1).