# Capable group of order 32

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A group that can be written as $G/Z(G)$ for some group $G$ is called capable. Can someone list the capable groups of order 32?

Comment: What did you tried to do? Do you know which groups of order $32$ exist at all?

Comment: I want to know if the following groups of order 32 are capable?                                  smallgroup(32,6), smallgroup(32,7), smallgroup(32,8), smallgroup(32,43), smallgroup(32,44).                                            Also we know that $D_{32}$ is capable.

Comment: The quaternion group $Q_{32}$ is not capable. For criteria see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/when-can-a-finite-group-be-written-as-the-quotient-of-some-other-group-by-its).

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde: What about the other groups?